# How do I remotely connect to my home router over a VPN, if there's another router with the same local IP in the local network?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nat

I'm running an OpenVPN server on a raspberry pi (192.168.1.2) at home. I'm at a friend's house and his router has the same local ip as my router at home (192.168.1.1).

I want to access my home router. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can’t. That’s the problem with using a common network address for a VPN. What you can do is change the network address for VPN to something very obscure and not commonly used like 172.21.92.x. You can do this by overhauling your network or setting up sophisticated One-to-one NAT rules on your router/VPN server that map all your internal IPs to the more obscure IPs over VPN.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign a new IP address scheme, one that wont be used by other routers that you may be visiting away from home. 10.0.0.1, 172.16.0.1, and 192.168.1.1 are very common defaults for consumer grade routers. Make your routers LAN address something like 10.10.100.1 255.255.255.0.

Second you need to port-forward your router, forwarding to the raspberry pi. The default for OpenVpn is port 1194 UDP. you can check to see if you are port forwarded properly by going to something like canyouseeme.org and checking to see if the port is open from your global IP address.

It is recommended to put your pi on a static IP address outside of your LAN DHCP pool.

That's pretty much it, you just cant have conflicting IP address pools when hosting a VPN.